# OpenVPN status active(exited) or loaded

Tags: openvpn

My OPENVPN installation is not working suddenly when I restart the computer.

The issue showing is that 1194 is already in use when that's not true.

Can anyone recommend me how to fix it?

Notes: The isssue showed is sometimes loaded and other active(exited) with the same origin /already in use)

[issue info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsIz2.png)

[issue info 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WybcQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please edit the question to include the necessary error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

I expect that OpenVPN is indeed already running, but you have not looked at it correctly.

Regardless, it seems like something is already bound to port 1194.   You can use fuser to find out the PID bound to a port.  (You will want to try both UDP and TCP, although UDP is more likely here)

```
   fuser -n udp 1194
```

Once you know the PID that is using port 1194 you can then get the process associated with the PID - for example, if the PID is 12345 then, as a quick and dirty way to get it try

```
   ps waux | grep "12345"
```